# VBA calls to user32.dll cursor modification

Tags: windows, vba, dll, windows-7, visio

**Short Question**
Is it possible to change the system cursor for a selected application (Visio 2010) using the `user32.dll`?

**Background**
I am trying to force a cursor to only show as an arrow, or better yet, remap the "hourglass" pointer to the arrow pointer so that when my Visio application is 'waiting' it will always show an arrow.  Thus far I have been able to load the `user32.dll` and call the `SetSystemCursor`, `LoadCursorA`, and `ShowCursor`.  Out of all of the calls made, only `ShowCursor` works as expected.

The issue may very well be that I don't fully understand what [`LoadCursor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`SetSystemCursor`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetSystemCursor.html) actually do.  I have linked the best documentation that I could find, which IMO is lacking at best.

**Closing Thoughts**
Is there a better way to accomplish this rather than using `user32.dll` the API?  Note that Visio 2010 does not, that I can find, control over the Mouse Pointers at all.

**Follow Up**
Check out [this post](http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=3634.0) for the exact behavior I am trying to get around.  Note that I am not trying to hide the application from showing it's busy.  I am trying to get rid of the hourglass flickering every time I change Visio shape data programmatically. [Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/50490956/SO_Help/Hourglass_Flashing_Example.vsd) is a link to the Visio Example I mention in the VisioGuy post, you must be a member of site to view attachments.

Originally I had no intent of using `LoadCursor` with `SetSystemCursor`, I only associated them because of the documentation I found at Pinvoke.net (for `SetSystemCursor`).  I had not seen the MSDN documentation for `SetSystemCursor`.  Thanks for the tip on Pinvoke... and I don't know why I didn't pull up the MSDN for both of them.

Admittedly, I have not played with system DLLs much.  My main knowledge base is in embedded systems, and OS independent languages (ie Python), so the tip about `SetSystemCursor` causing global system errors is the kind of information that I really need.

Comment: Visio can always change the cursor - you'd have to recognize when the cursor changed to an Hourglass, then reset it to a Pointer. That isn't practical, imho, since it turns to an Hourglass when it is busy and thus isn't able to execute your change cursor macro.

Comment: @MattH: I do agree that it is not that practical to monitor for the change.  The hope would be to, in some way, remap the hour glass decal to the arrow cursor while in Visio. Check out my edit to see the exact issue I am trying to get around.

Comment: I see you've mentioned `LoadCursor` and `SetSystemCursor` - I assume you've read the [docs for the latter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648395(v=vs.85).aspx): "*hcur* cannot be a cursor loaded using the `LoadCursor` function."?

Comment: The MSDN docs for SetSystemCursor() specifically mentions that you can't pass it a cursor you got from LoadCursor().  It is a pretty evil function anyway, you'll break the cursor for *all* applications.  Permanently if Visio crashes.  Just don't go there.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on pinvoke.net to give you documentation for what functions do - it exists primarily to assist people with calling functions that they already understand, to some extent. For Win32, MSDN should always be treated as the primary resource.

Comment: You can't change the Hourglass cursor for Visio. You can change the Hourglass cursor for a system/Windows user, the same way cursors can be customized for a theme/user. You could try to detect when Visio has the application focus, change the Hourglass cursor for the system, then restore it when Visio loses focus.

Comment: Isn't changing the cursor to an hourglass expected behavior when an app is "busy"? I don't see why that would be a poor reflection on your application, since Visio users would be expecting it.

Comment: @JP.  It's not that I am trying to hide that it is busy.  I am changing shape data in Visio at a fairly rapid rate and each time an object is changed the cursor flashes momentarily.  This does not functionally hurt anything, it is just *very* hard to ignore.  See my first Follow Up link for more information.

Comment: Can you hide Windows cursor with ShowCursor(false), draw a fake busy one while you're doing your work, and restore Windows cursor?

Comment: @SimonMourier: Check out the link in my follow up for what the end goal is.  Setting ShowCursor false, from my testing, only makes the situation worse.  On top of that, I'm not quite sure how I would draw a fake cursor.

Comment: I don't see a sample attached from the link in visguy. Can you post it somewhere (else)?

Answer (score 0):

Although it does not strictly answer the 'cursor modification' question, I think you should be able to use Visio's Application object properties:

- The [Application.ScreenUpdating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff767454.aspx) Property
- The [Application.ShowChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff766801.aspx) Property

At least, this will allow you to hide the cursor while you're doing your background processing. I have tested this with your sample on visguy and it does not show painless cursor changes anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the links.  The only problem is that the background task is on-going.  It's a Python socket server that is controlling Visio, via COM, which can update the diagram at any point.  These changes, in general, are short but can sometimes become lengthy.  After looking a bit closer, I think these will help more than I originally thought.  Thanks!